# GRUB can't access my linux partition?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bootloader, grubrescue

Until now I had 2 NTFS partitions on my harddrive. Now I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04, so i freed 100GB from the end of my harddrive, created a new ext4 partition, and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

That's how my partitions table look:

```
/dev/sda1 - 98.81GB NTFS
/dev/sda5 - 732.71GB NTFS
/dev/sda6 - 100.00GB EXT4
```

The GRUB has written the data to the harddrive's MBR, however it seems that it can't access the `/dev/sda6/` partition. IT boots up to resuce mode, and when I type `ls` I can only see `(hd0)` and `(hd0,ms-dos)`.

1. Is it because the boot files are on an extended partition? If so, how can I make it a primary partition without reformatting my harddrive?
2. If grub support extended partitions, where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend repairing grub: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: grub is installed correctly. I tried doing what is shown on this guide but nothing changed. still booting into resuce mode.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I can add a bounty if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that GRUB doesn't support extended partitions.

Comment: GRUB does support booting to installations located within extended partitions: many if not most Ubuntu and other GNU/Linux installs using GRUB meet that description, as well as almost every Ubuntu system installed automatically (i.e., without manual partitioning) alongside another OS (such as Windows).